# Problems with iterators

Tags: c++

```
void Reverse(vector<int> v)
{
    vector<int>::iterator itr1 = v.begin();
    vector<int>::reverse_iterator itr2 = v.rbegin();
    while(true)
    {
        swap(*itr1,*itr2);
        itr1++;
        if(itr1 == itr2.base() - 1) break;
        itr2++;
    }
}
```

Function should reverse the vector, but it is not working.
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: "not working" isn't a problem description.

Comment: Read about passing by value and by reference in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: You're passing a copy to the function. Also, std::reverse?

Comment: Maybe it's because you pass the vector `v` *by value*?

Comment: Use `std::reverse`

Comment: `if(itr1 == itr2.base() - 1) break;` is not a safe end condition. it'll miss either all even or all odd sized vectors, and result in undefined behaviour. You also can't pass an empty vector to this.

Comment: @JeJo or just do two comparisons, `(itr1 == itr2.base()) || (itr1 == itr2.base() - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

It reverses a local copy. You probably want

```
void Reverse(vector<int>& v)
```

or `std::reverse`

Comment: It also tests for equality of the two iterator, midway. This will only work for odd-sized vectors.